# Why can't I find "Self Service.app"?

Tags: macos, mdm

I am trying to find [this Self Service.app](https://support.sou.edu/kb/articles/how-to-install-self-service-software-on-a-macintosh) but it is no where to be found. Not on Spotlight, not on /Applications. Everywhere I read about it, it is assumed as a given that it should be there when the mac OS is installed.

I have Mojave 10.14.3.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That application comes from the MDM provider. When it’s missing, that means the enrollment profile is broken or was removed. You would follow the enrollment process (typically going to a web address and downloading a new copy of the enrollment profile) or contact the help desk to get them to send you a new enrollment.

When you accept the enrollment, that application is one of the first things the MDM delivers to your Mac.

Since your MDM uses JAMF, you can open terminal and get more details with this command.

```
sudo jamf manage
```

If the MDM allows your credentials to re-enroll and the jamf binary is still also installed, you can possible re-enroll

```
    sudo jamf enroll --prompt
```